Usage of PaginatorHelper in CakePHP 4
I am migrating my project from CakePHP 3 to 4, and the Paginator component I was using previously has been deprecated.
Here's what they have been replaced with: Pagination and PaginatorHelper.
How am I supposed to access the PaginatorHelper in a controller?
I can't use it in a view because my controller is for an API, which returns a JSON response (so I don't have a template).
I would need to access the total method on the PaginatorHelper to expose the value in my JSON response, to enable the client to correctly handle the pagination.
However, I am unable to correctly instantiate the PaginatorHelper in my controller.
Here's what I've tried so far:
class ApiController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->viewBuilder()
            ->addHelper('Paginator')
            ->setClassName('Json');
    }

    public function list(int $limit = 10, int $page = 1)
    {
        $query = $this->People->find('visible')
            ->order(['lastname' => 'ASC']);

        $paginateSettings = [
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page,
            'maxLimit' => 100
        ];

        $this->set('people', $this->paginate($query, $paginateSettings));

        $this->set('page', $page);
        $this->set('pages', $this->Paginator->total());

        $this->viewBuilder()
            ->setOption('serialize', ['people', 'page', 'pages']);
    }
}

I've also tried moving the addHelper() call to beforeRender() instead of initialize(), but that didn't change anything:
    public function beforeRender(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeRender($event);

        $this->viewBuilder()
            ->addHelper('Paginator');
    }

But I aways get the error
Notice: Undefined property: ApiController::$Paginator
Uncaught exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function total() on null'

I think I'm doing everything according to the helpers documentation. So what's the problem here?

First thing : did you well removed the alias ->setClassName('Json'); before trying?

@b126 but why should I remove it? I do need the Json output.

In the end, it turns out that it's not necessary to use the PaginatorHelper in the controller to access those pagination parameters.
As mentioned here,

You can access the pagination metadata at $this->request->getAttribute('paging').

The array this method returns contains all the needed parameters:
[
    'People' => [
        'count' => (int) 28,
        'current' => (int) 28,
        'perPage' => (int) 30,
        'page' => (int) 1,
        'requestedPage' => (int) 1,
        'pageCount' => (int) 1,
        'start' => (int) 1,
        'end' => (int) 28,
        'prevPage' => false,
        'nextPage' => false,
        'sort' => null,
        'direction' => null,
        'sortDefault' => false,
        'directionDefault' => false,
        'completeSort' => [ ],
        'limit' => null,
        'scope' => null,
        'finder' => 'all',
    ],
]

